# App refused for notifying user when new version of app is available

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I recently released a new version of my app which now contains some code which at run time, checks for a new version of the app. If a new version exists, an alert will appear asking the user if they want to download the new version now or later. This notification appears when user opens app app, and if they say no will not appear again, until app process is killed and then opened again. So the notification is not intrusive

However Apple rejected my app saying

"Your app includes an update button or alerts the user to update the app. To avoid user confusion, app version updates must utilize the iOS built-in update mechanism. "

There are frameworks online you can add to your app like this

https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren

Which do this, and I believe clash of clans notify users when app update is available. So how come my app is being refused for this feature.

Is there another way I can notify users that a version of the app is available that will not cause the app to be refused.

Any info would be much appreciated

Comment: Wow sorry to hear, we were thinking about using this framework as well.

Comment: I've never heard of Siren leading to app rejection. You may have improperly configured Siren by exposing a button to the end-user when an update was not available. Please shoot me a Direct Message on Twitter (@ArtSabintsev) or at my email (<arthur>@<sabintsev>.<com>) and I can assist.